# how to use mathematical symbol / latex math in coefficient names in msummary from modelsummary package?

Tags: r

Some of my regressors contain math symbols, say something like \lambda in latex format.

And I want to export my regression model result to a .tex file.

I cannot find any reference that shows how I can add math symbol to my variable names.

The main example from the vignettes does not have math symbol or sub/superscripts in it.

[image]

I tried

```
cm <- c('lambda'='$\\lambda$')
```

in my case.

But the exported tex file only recogonize the whole expression as texts. '' was recogonized as \textbacklash.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`modelsummary` uses `kableExtra` to produce LaTeX code. By default, `kableExtra` escapes underscores and other such characters to ensure proper compilation under LaTeX. You can send any argument to `kableExtra` via the `...` ellipsis in `msummary`. This allows you to set `escape=FALSE` to avoid `\textbackslash` insertion.

For example:

```r
library(modelsummary)
#> Loading required package: tables
cm <- c("hp" = "$\\lambda$")
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)
tab <- msummary(mod, "latex", coef_map = cm, escape=FALSE)
print(tab)
#> \begin{table}[H]
#> \centering
#> \begin{tabular}{ll}
#> \toprule
#>   & Model 1\\
#> \midrule
#> $\lambda$ & -0.068\\
#>  & (0.010)\\
#> \midrule
#> Num.Obs. & 32\\
#> R2 & 0.602\\
#> R2 Adj. & 0.589\\
#> AIC & 181.2\\
#> BIC & 185.6\\
#> Log.Lik. & -87.619\\
#> \bottomrule
#> \end{tabular}
#> \end{table}
```

Note that this will affect the *whole* table. This may be a problem if your table includes other non-LaTeX-friendly characters.